# Express m-th times switched rows matrix A in terms of determinant A and m

Tags: determinant

Let $A'$ be obtained from the square matrix $A$ by interchanging pairs of rows (columns) *m* times. Express $\det A'$ in terms of $\det A$ and *m*.

I have this question in my Assignment, but I unable to understand the question. Is there anyone who can help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ determinant(A') = (-1)^m determinant( A)$$